# How to send password change email instead of verification email for a new user in Auth0 in 2024

Tags: node.js, auth0

Hi I am trying to do this same thing as in this question here:
[How to send password change email instead of verification email for a new user in Auth0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65578003/17626698)

I am basically trying to do the same thing but put the code into the auth0 actions instead of rules and hooks like it used to be before.

I tried looking through the auth0 documentation and forums but i didn't find an answer.
This is the closest i found to an answer on the auth0 forums: https://community.auth0.com/t/auth0-password-change-with-actions/119868

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Auth0 actions. Follow below steps

1. Go to `Actions -> Library -> Click Create Action -> Select Build From Scratch -> Then add this to the script`

```
/**
* Handler that will be called during the execution of a PostUserRegistration flow.
*
* @param {Event} event - Details about the context and user that has registered.
* @param {PostUserRegistrationAPI} api - Methods and utilities to help change the behavior after a signup.
*/

var axios = require("axios").default;

exports.onExecutePostUserRegistration = async (event, api) => {

    var data = {
      'client_id': event.client_id,
      'email': event.user.email,
      'connection': event.connection.name
    }

    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    await axios.post("https://<Auth0_Tenant_Domain>.auth0.com/dbconnections/change_password", data, {
        headers: headers
    });

};
```

Make sure to add axios inside dependencies

[image]

What we have done here is access the change password email through the Auth Management API and execute the procedure after user registration

2. Now save and deploy the changes.
3. Now go to `Actions -> Flows -> Post User Registration -> Go to the custom tab and drag and drop your action card between start and complete`.

[image]

4. Now click on Apply button.

Try this out and let me know the result

Comment: I tried testing the code you gave me and I am getting this error message:
Error:

{
  "code": "ERR_INVALID_URL",
  "message": "Invalid URL",
  "name": "TypeError",
  "stack": "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL\...
I changed the URL you gave me to the one I should use so I am not using the default URL that you wrote I am using the correct one

Comment: That is why I have mentioned as `https://<Auth0_Tenant_Domain>.auth0.com/dbconnections/change_password` **(<Auth0_Tenant_Domain>)** because I don't know your tenant name.